# Don't load/scan class files from a specific jar

Tags: apache-felix, bnd, maven-bundle-plugin

I'd like to know how to configure the maven-bundle-plugin (backed by bnd) to completely ignore the classes contained within an embedded jar.

**Background**

I'm working in a controlled environment where the environment my code is running on is defined by a single company (including all the tools). The code is java and uses OSGi to define module dependencies.

Some of the provided modules contain what look like invalid class files, I can only assume that the system will 'correct' these class files before it tries to load them into any type of JVM. In any case these class files work when deployed onto the target system.

I'm trying to create a build system based on Maven that can produce packages the system understands and have hit a problem where these invalid class files are being read by BND (via apache-felix) which causes errors.

I'd like a way to have the jars that contain these class files on the class path of the bundle but where the contained `.class` files aren't read/processed by bnd. I could settle for simply ignoring the errors and continuing but can't find a way to do that either without felix aborting the entire build phase.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the `-failok` directive, don't know why I didn't find it before. Adding `<_failok>true</_failok>` to the instructions allows me to continue working.

See [instructions-ref](http://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/825-instructions-ref.html)

Comment: If someone comes up with a better (less hacky) solution then I will change my accepted answer, for now I'll leave it here.